# Reading text file using PHP

Tags: php, file, text

I have a text file, and it contains company names and prices. Like this:

```
first company name
2,2
second company name
2,7
third company name
1,9
```

The problem is that I can't read and show data properly. My code:

```
<?php
$content=file("test_data.txt");

foreach ($content as $data)
{
    $data = array(
    'company' => $content[0], 
    'price' => $content[1]
    );
    echo $data['company'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $data['price'];
}
?>
```

What is wrong? I need also to send data to SQL database, but first I would have to clarify the code above.

Comment: You should do some additional research on `foreach` because I think you've misunderstood the way they work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beacuse `file` function returns array of lines. And you loop lien by line, you should loop file by line-pairs. You can do it like this:

```
$lines = file("test_data.txt");
$data = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i += 2)
{
    $pair = array();
    $pair['company'] = $lines[$i];
    $pair['price'] = $lines[$i + 1];
    $data[] = $pair;
}
```

`$data` array should look similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [company] => first company name
            [price] => 2,2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [company] => second company name
            [price] => 2,7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [company] => third company name
            [price] => 1,9
        )

)
```